# difference between latitude, longitude, accuracy, bearing, altitude and time

Tags: location

i just want to make this thing clear. to get the location, we could use

```
int lat = (int)(location.getLatitude());
int lng = (int)(location.getLongitude());
int acc = (int) (location.getAccuracy());
int alt = (int) (location.getAltitude());
int bearing = (int) (location.getBearing());
```

so what is the relationship with all of this? how does the accuracy would make the location more accurate than only using just latitude and longitude? and what is the correct way in representing all of this information? i mean as we see in the google maps or any other maps, the location will be as 110'30'N. so, where are we actually using the latitude, longitude, accuracy, bearing, altitude and time?

any information regarding this that make this thing clear once and for all is really appreciated. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latitude and longitude are your locations on a flat map. It doesn't tell if you're on the ground or on an airplane. This is what Google Maps may display as `10'13"N 100'12"W`

Altitude tells you your altitude from sea level, which means that the 3 mentioned together give your position in "3D".

Accuracy tells how accurate the location hardware (GPS?) deems your location to be. It doesn't in any way make the reading more accurate, just tells you how wrong the other values may be.

Bearing is where you're pointing, ie which direction you're heading (think compass).